# how to realize a network-based book query system

Tags: c++, c

Please notice that if i do not want to use database.

i am now learning Unix networking programming. And i have my university book library all book list in seperated txt files. for example, the 'b' begin books is stored in b.txt. all a-z book count is about 1 million record. a line for a book' name and detailed other info.

Now i want to do a program to provide the query service of book list, for example, giving a book name, it can return the detailed info of this bool  is it exists.

So i need to first build a module to take the function of query.

Then write the server side to call the query module and get the result and sending the result to the client module.

My question is , if i do not using database.  How to realize the query module using c/c++, just  first locating the first letter, for example, `H` begin book name should find in `H.txt` or `H1.txt` and `H2.txt`, using `fopen` open the file, then read line by line, then compare with queried book name using `strFind`, `strCmp` similar function, if have then return the result. i just think this is a time consuming thing and is not realize for using. And if have any such query system could for reference not using database but is bearable in time?

Comment: C or C++? Pick one. Note that "c/c++" does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options. The cheapest option (=low development time, low maintenance, low hardware requirements), IMO, is to create a html page on a separate site that links to all the data files. Then you set up another page that uses google.com to search that site. Then you just tell the google web spider to index your site. That way you get excellent performance with minimal work. But... you don't get to program any C.

Simple solution using C:

Do as you yourself suggest. If you have lots of memory available for file caching the performance won't be so bad unless the load gets high.
There will still be some work to do with the rest of the solution since you should delegate the search to worker threads.

Intermediate solution using C:

Find a 3rd party search engine and integrate it with your network code.

Advanced solution using C:

Implement your own search engine.

Comment: could u explain the simple solution using c? now my level is can read a file line by line and compare with keywords. especially in "file caching" and "worker threads", do you mean that its a multi-thread thing?

Comment: how to look up in your profile. @Lightness Races in Orbit?

Comment: @user1279988 File caching is usually left for the OS to handle. 
If this is a school assignment then the assignment should state whether a multi-threaded solution is required.

Comment: @Klas Lindbäck no, this is not a school assignment. i am a junior developer who have  graduated. But want to transfer to unix networking area jobs. So i want to have some task have realize meaning to practice after i have read some books.

Comment: Then I recommend that you focus on the networking part and start off with a simple search. You can replace it with a more advanced search later, when the networking parts are completed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is **WHY DON'T U WANT TO USE DATABASE** ?

### 1. make it easier to deploy?

[sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) may a good choice .

### 2. trying another method ?

lucene is a good choice of information retrieval, which is written by java.

[clucene](http://clucene.sourceforge.net/) is someone rewrite the lucene to c .

You may also need stemmer tool(get the root of words),ictclas(chinese words' term extract) etc .

### 3. would like to do anything by yourself ?

It is easy to manage text file in system , while , as for a "query system", **store** is not enough , the main problem is IR(information retrieval ).
You may learn something about index building, store and query the index